# Cannot load temporary file in VBCodeProvider

Tags: vb.net, function

Here's my script code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Script
Implements IScript

Public Sub DoWork(w As WebBrowser, f As Form1) Implements IScript.DoWork
    w.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    wait("5000")
    w.Document.All("input").InvokeMember("click")
    w.Document.All("input").SetAttribute("value", "Torrenter is the best!")
    wait("2000")
    w.Document.All("421").InvokeMember("click")
wait("1000")
End Sub

Public Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
        ' Allows UI to remain responsive
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
End Sub
```

End Class

In-code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If int1.Text = "1" Then
        int1.Text = "0"
        Dim script As IScript = GenerateScript(File.ReadAllText(ListBox2.Items.Item(int2).ToString()))
        script.DoWork(WebBrowser1, Me) 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        int2 = int2 + 1
        int1.Text = "1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Why? :(
It's supposed to start the next script after the first was done. I tried 4 methods but I can't understand why.

Comment: Could you add, to your question, the whole call-stack from the exception?  Also, does this happen on your development machine, or only on certain other machines?  Did you check `results.Errors.HasErrors` to see if it actually successfully compiled?

Comment: You made me the code yesterday :)
I'll search for some more info

Comment: Yes, but I don't get that exception on my machine.  I tested it first before posting it.  Also, my code that I posted did have an `If` statement that checked if it had errors.  You have removed that check in this code.

Comment: I removed it and replaced the array string with a simple string because the text was already converted. Should I post here my entire code? It's not too long

Comment: My code was adding the `Imports` statement to the top of the source code before compiling it.  Perhaps with that missing, it is failing to compile.

Comment: Updated the whole code - That's the code I use, so...what's the problem?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how it even compiles with you passing a string into that `CompileAssemblyFromSource` method, since it only accepts an array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx).  Perhaps you have `Option Strict Off` (which is a bad idea)?

Comment: Can you also provide an example script source code string that you are passing to it which is failing?

Comment: Done. I can't figure out what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your script code is failing to compile, but then you are trying to instantiate an object from the compiled assembly anyway.  Since it failed to compile, the assembly doesn't actually exist, hence the error.  If you modify the `Return` line in the `GenerateScript` method, so that it shows the compile errors, the actual problem will be more clear:

```
Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codes)
If results.Errors.HasErrors Then
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    builder.AppendLine("Script failed to compile due to the following errors:")
    For Each i As CompilerError In results.Errors
        builder.AppendFormat("Line {0}: {1}", i.Line, i.ErrorText)
        builder.AppendLine()
    Next
    Throw New Exception(builder.ToString())
Else
    Return CType(results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Script"), IScript)
End If
```

I suspect that one of the reasons it's failing to compile is because the script uses `IScript` which is undefined.  The reason it would complain that it's undefined is for two reasons.  First, you declared the `IScript` interface as nested inside the `Form1` class.  You should move that outside of the form class so that it's not nested inside of any other type.  Second, you are not specifying the full namespace nor importing the namespace in your script.  You can automatically add the `Imports` line to the beginning of the script code before compiling it, like this:

```
Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
Dim codes As String = "Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code
```

As I mentioned in the comments above, you really ought to be passing a string array into the `CompileAssemblyFromSource` method, not a string.  I'm not sure how that even compiles, unless that's something having `Option Strict Off` somehow allows?  In any case, it expects an array, so you should really be giving it one, like this:

```
Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
Dim codeArray() As String = New String() {"Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code}
Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeArray)
```

Another obvious reason why the script would fail to compile is because you have it using methods and properties of your `Form1` class, as if it were a member of that class.  Remember, the `Script` class defined by the script file source code is a completely separate class in a separate assembly.  It will have no reference to the form unless you give it a reference, for instance, you could define the interface like this:

```
Public Interface IScript
    Sub DoWork(f As Form1)
End Interface
```

Then, in your script, you could do this:

```
Public Class Script
    Implements IScript
    Public Sub DoWork(f As Form1) Implements IScript.DoWork
        f.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
        f.wait("5000")
        f.wait("4000")
        f.WebBrowser1.Document.All("input").InvokeMember("click")
        f.WebBrowser1.Document.All("input").SetAttribute("value", "User")
        f.wait("2000")
        f.WebBrowser1.Document.All("421").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub
End Class
```

### UPDATE

Ok, since you can't get it working, and I don't want this whole conversation to be a total loss, I put together a working project and tested it.  Here's what you need to do to get it to work.

**Contents of IScript.vb**

```
Public Interface IScript
    Sub DoWork(w As WebBrowser)
End Interface
```

**Contents of Form1.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim int1 As Integer = 0
    Dim int2 As Integer = 0
    Dim p As Point

    Public Function GenerateScript(ByVal code As String) As IScript
        Using provider As New VBCodeProvider()
            Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = True
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(GetType(WebBrowser).Assembly.Location)
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
            Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
            code = "Imports System.Windows.Forms" & Environment.NewLine & "Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code
            Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code)
            If results.Errors.HasErrors Then
                Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
                builder.AppendLine("Script failed to compile due to the following errors:")
                For Each i As CompilerError In results.Errors
                    builder.AppendFormat("Line {0}: {1}", i.Line, i.ErrorText)
                    builder.AppendLine()
                Next
                Throw New Exception(builder.ToString())
            Else
                Return CType(results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Script"), IScript)
            End If
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each File As FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "/scripts").GetFiles
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(int2) = CheckState.Checked Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(File.FullName)
            End If
            int2 = int2 + 1
        Next
        int2 = 0
        Dim script As IScript = GenerateScript(File.ReadAllText(ListBox1.Items.Item(int2).ToString()))
        script.DoWork(WebBrowser1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Contents of script file**

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Script
    Implements IScript

    Public Sub DoWork(w As WebBrowser) Implements IScript.DoWork
        w.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
        wait("5000")
        wait("4000")
        w.Document.All("input").InvokeMember("click")
        w.Document.All("input").SetAttribute("value", "User")
        wait("2000")
        w.Document.All("421").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Public Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
            ' Allows UI to remain responsive
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        sw.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One problem, it may sound a bit nooby but what should I put as f1?
`DoWork(what?)`      Oh yeah and the `DoWork(f1 as Form1)` automatically changes to `DoWork(ByVal f As Form1)`

Comment: To pass the current form, call it this way: `DoWork(Me)`

Comment: Interesting...DoWork doesn't exist. I can't call it. That's strange

Comment: I'm happy to help, but, for what it's worth, I never recommend using code that you don't fully understand.  This stuff is slightly more advanced than what most .NET programmers deal with.  It's nothing outrageously complicated, but if you're having trouble grasping what's going on, I'd strongly recommend taking the time to learn more of the basics before trying to tackle something like this, if possible.

Comment: I understand. But I'll get it somehow :). The only thing I don't know is how could I start another script after the first was done.

Comment: Using the same script file, or a different one?

Comment: a different one. I don't want to waste your time with this, so you can just answer me this question and then I'll figure it out :D

Comment: Well, just selecting a different script in the list and clicking the button again would launch a second script, but if you wanted to do two in a row, you could simply create a second script object, like `Dim script2 As IScript = GenerateScript(...)` and then after calling `script.DoWork(Me)`, you could just call `script2.DoWork(Me)`.

Comment: And that would make the 2nd script to start after the first script has ended?

Comment: Yes.  The `DoWork` method is synchronous.  Unless you are starting a new thread to call `DoWork`, or you are creating a new thread inside of `DoWork`, then it will be a synchronous call meaning that it will not return until it is done doing whatever it is that it does.

Comment: Ok, so I've got the errors (the real ones):
`Type 'IScript' is not defined.`  and   `Type 'Form1' is not defined`

Comment: That's because you aren't importing the namespace, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Sadly I can't get to the answer :(
  Even if I import all the namespaces it shows me the same error

Comment: Finally works. I want to thank you for all the work and because you helped me so much.

Comment: Yay!  No problem.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: I've just got a new error, but I think it's not something too hard. Could you please look at the 2nd update in my first post?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Which object is null?  script?

Comment: `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in qjxzcxh5` So...I think it's a temporary file problem

Comment: Ah, the `CreateInstance` method returns `Nothing` if the specified type (i.e. `Script`) is not found in the assembly.  That must be what's happening.  Are you sure the second script also defines a class called `Script`?

Comment: So you are definitely loading the same script file both times, and it works the first time but fails the second time?

Comment: No, no no. I load the first script, then with the same declared variable named Script, I load and execute the 2nd script from the list. There's where the error appears

Comment: Which script did you show in your question?  The first one or the second one?  Are you sure that the second time you are passing the correct script, and not just an empty string or something?

Comment: No, the string it's ok. I think I need to declare another variable every time I load a new script, but after the proverious script is done.